# Angular (Ionic) - API - How to Post Data ordered

Tags: angular, api, rest, symfony

I am working on an APi where a store could define its priorities for a product.

The first one would be "price" obligatory and the others would be its choice of priorities.

I want to send these choices to my Symfony back.
[image: Render of the page]

I can see in my consoles the data values which will be sent
[image: Data sent and connection errors]

I found only examples on Google and I am not sure how to adapt it to my exercice and why the connection doesn't work. My Get works on another page with the same endpoint (and a different method inside).

```
  prios: Prios[];
  apiUrl = 'http://localhost:8000/api/prio';
  listItems: any;
  item = [
    // {value: 'Price', viewValue: ' Price'},
    { value: "New", viewValue: "Release Date of product" },
    {
      value: "Size",
      viewValue: "Size of product"
    },
    {
      value: "Area",
      viewValue: "Product delivery area"
    }
  ];

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.listItems = [
      // 'Price',
      "Release Date of product",
      "Size of product",
      "Product delivery area"
    ];
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.http.get<any[]>(this.apiUrl).subscribe(data => {
      this.prios = data;
    });
  }

  postData() {
    let url = `${this.apiUrl}/`;
    this.http
        .post(url, {
          prio1: "price",
          prio2: this.item[0],
          prio3: this.item[1],
          prio4: this.item[2]
        })
        .subscribe(res => console.log(this.http.post()));
  }
```

Did I miss a step?

Comment: Frist, Does your route accept post methods? Second, how do you handle the POST in your backend? It seems that your backend throws an error because it does not know how to handle your POST action. Third, after you subscribe to your post, do not log _this.http.post()_, rather do _.subscribe((response)=> {console.log(response)})_ to log the response of your backend. You could use Postman to try debug your backend

Comment: Thanks  user2403735, sorry I figure it out after a while